# Lebesgue outer measure of image of function with bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I encountered the following problem in my real analysis course this past semester:

Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $[a,b]$. Suppose that $E \subset [a,b]$ and that $f'$ exists and is bounded on $E$, say, by $M$. Prove that $\lambda^*(f(E)) \leq M\lambda^*(E)$.

(source: Exercise 8.18 in A Course in Real Analysis 2nd Ed., by McDonald and Weiss)

Here is what I have so far:

Consider the special case when $E$ is an open set. Then $E$ is the disjoint union of countably many open intervals $(I_n)_n$. Pick any such open interval $I_n$. Let $x,y \in I_n$. By the Mean Value Theorem, $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|$. But $|x-y| \leq \lambda^*(I_n)$. Therefore $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M\lambda^*(I_n)$ for any $x,y \in I_n$. It follows that $\lambda^*(f(I_n)) \leq M\lambda^*(I_n)$. Summing over all $n$ and using subadditivity of Lebesgue outer measure yields the desired inequality.

For an arbitrary set $E$, I considered using the formal definition of Lebesgue outer measure. Pick a countable set of open intervals $(I_n)_n$ that covers $E$. I may assume without loss of generality that the sum of lengths is within some $\epsilon > 0$ of $\lambda^*(E)$. Then I wish to show that there is some countable set of open intervals $(J_n)_n$ that covers $f(E)$ so that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(f(J_n)) \leq M\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(f(I_n)).$$ However, this seems to me equally insoluble. The fact that $f'$ may not be bounded and may not even exist outside $E$ seems to make things particularly complicated, since an interval $I_n$ may not be contained in $E$. What key insights am I missing?

Comment: If you can show it for open sets then perhaps try using outer regularity of Lebesgue measure to show it for general sets.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying to use the fact that there are open sets $O_1 \supset O_2 \supset \dots \supset E$ such that $\lambda^*(E) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda^*(O_n)$? The problem I encountered with this is that the condition $|f'(x)| \leq M$ does not necessarily hold on all of $O_n$, so I couldn't figure out how to apply my proof for open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the starting point is that having a bound on $f'$ at a point $x$ does allow you to control the growth of $f$ near $x$, even if $f$ is not differentiable at these nearby points.

The assumption allows us to get local control of $f$ in the following way: for each $x \in E$ we have 
$$ \lim_{y \to x} \frac{\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert}{\lvert x - y \rvert} \leq M,$$
so we can choose $\delta_x > 0$ such that
$$0 < \lvert x - y \rvert \leq \delta_x \quad\text{implies}\quad \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leq (M + \varepsilon)\lvert x - y \rvert.$$
So points near $x$, whether or not they are in $E$, can't be mapped too far from $f(x)$.

Now we have the problem of using this to control the measure of the image of $E$. First we give ourselves a little bit of room around $E$: by definition of outer measure, we can take an open set $U \supseteq E$ such that $\lambda^*(U) \leq \lambda^*(E) + \varepsilon$.
We can also require that $\delta_x$ is small enough that $[x - \delta_x, x+\delta_x] \subset U$. Denote $$B_x = [x-\delta_x, x+\delta_x].$$

We now use these intervals to approximate the measure of $E$ using some covering lemmas: [Vitali's covering lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma#From_the_covering_lemma_to_the_covering_theorem) gives a countable subset $E' \subset E$ and new radii $\delta'_x \leq \delta_x$ for $x \in E'$ such that the intervals $B_x' = [x - \delta_x', x+\delta_x']$ are disjoint and still cover $E$, minus some set $N \subset E$ of outer measure zero. By choice of $\delta_x$, we also have $$f(B_x') \subseteq [f(x) - (M + \varepsilon) \delta_x',\ f(x) + (M + \varepsilon) \delta_x']$$ so that in particular $\lambda^*(f(B_x')) \leq (M + \varepsilon) \lvert B_x' \rvert.$ Furthermore,
$$f(E\setminus N) \subseteq f\left(\bigcup_{x \in E'} B_x'\right) = \bigcup_{x \in E'} f(B_x')$$
so, using that the intervals $B_x'$ are disjoint and are contained in $U$,
$$ \lambda^* (f(E\setminus N)) \leq \sum_{x \in E'} \lambda^*(f(B_x')) \leq \sum_{x \in E'} (M + \varepsilon) \lvert B_x' \rvert = (M + \varepsilon) \lambda\left(\bigcup_{x \in E'} B_x' \right)\leq (M + \varepsilon) \lambda(U) \leq (M + \varepsilon)[\lambda^*(E) + \varepsilon]. \tag{1}$$

Now we need to control what happens on the null set $N$. To do this we can use a different covering lemma: First take an open set $V \supset N$ with $\lambda(V) \leq \varepsilon$, and for each $x \in N$ choose $\eta_x \leq \delta_x$ so that $[x - \eta_x, x+\eta_x] \subset V$. By [Besicovitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besicovitch_covering_theorem), there is some collection of points $N' \subset N$ such that the corresponding intervals $I_x = [x - \eta_x, x+\eta_x]$ have *bounded overlap*; more precisely, there is some constant $C$ (independent of the original cover) such that each point of $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in at most $C$ of the intervals. Similarly to above, but using bounded overlap instead of disjointness, we get the bound
$$ \lambda^*(f(N)) \leq \sum_{x \in N'} \lambda^*( f(I_x)) \leq \sum_{x \in N'} (M + \varepsilon) \lvert I_x \rvert \leq C (M + \varepsilon) \lambda \left( \bigcup_{x \in N'} I_x \right) \leq C(M + \varepsilon) \lambda(V) \leq C(M + \varepsilon) \varepsilon. \tag{2}$$

Combining (1) and (2) via subadditivity, we get
$$ \lambda^*(f(E)) \leq \lambda^*(f(E \setminus N)) + \lambda^*(f(N)) \leq (M + \varepsilon)[\lambda^*(E) + \varepsilon] + C(M + \varepsilon) \varepsilon. $$
Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives the result.

Comment: Thank you. I'm confused about one thing - why does a maximal element of $\mathcal{E}$ necessarily give a cover of $E$? Could there be some $x \in E$ such that there are intervals approaching $x$ on either side but no intervals containing $x$? It seems to me that this might not contradict the maximality condition, since it's not possible to add an interval containing $x$ with positive length.

Comment: @DhruvRohatgi Excellent point, I should have been more careful. I've replaced that lemma with two standard ones, but now it's getting a bit long. Do you suspect there's a nicer solution? I'm not familiar with the textbook, so I don't know what theorems have been introduced before the exercise, what the previous exercises were, how complex the solutions tend to be, etc.

Comment: I suspect there is a nicer solution. The Vitali Covering Theorem was introduced, but Besicovitch's Covering Theorem was not. In my experience the solutions to exercises in this textbook were usually simpler than this, but perhaps sometimes not by much.